# Can't ssh permission denied. HBase Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, ssh, amazon-ec2, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I have an amazon ec2 instance that I'm running a tool called seqware on. It's basically a query engine for genomic data that uses an hbase backend. I'm running on an ami that comes with hbase set up in pseudo distributed mode. I would like to use it in a fully distributed mode however. So I have set up a 2 node hadoop cluster. One node is the master and the other is a slave. I can run hadoop examples in fully distributed mode and everything. To make seqware use my fully ditrbuted set up, it needs 6 things, the zookeeper quorum, zookeeper client port, hbase master, the mapred job tracker , the fs default fs and fs name. Which are specified, in a setting file. I have it set up in the file as so:

```
HBASE.ZOOKEEPER.QUORUM=ip-10-x.x.x
HBASE.ZOOKEEPER.PROPERTY.CLIENTPORT=2181
HBASE.MASTER=ip-10-x.x.x:60010
MAPRED.JOB.TRACKER=ip-10-x.x.x:9001
FS.DEFAULT.NAME=hdfs://ip-10-x.x.x:9000
FS.DEFAULTFS=hdfs://ip-10-x.x.x:9000
```

However, when I started using the query engine, I was getting a zookeeper connection loss exception. I had the the public key for the master in the authorized_keys for seqware and vice versa, however, I couldn't  ssh as so

```
ssh ip-10.x.x.x
```

or even using the public dns:

```
ssh {public DNS of instance}
```

where ip-10.x.x.x is the ip address of the instance, I had to do it using the username:

```
ssh {username}@ip-10-x.x.x
```

or

```
ssh username@{public DNS of instance}
```

I can ssh without the username from the master to slave hadoop instance and vice versa, and I have the ip address in the config files without the username

I tryed adding the username before the ip address in the settings, thinking that there a 99% chance it wouldn't work, and I wasn't disappointed, I still got the same exception

What do I need to do so that I can ssh from the seqware instance into the hadoop and hbase master without having to specify a username, as I do between the master and slave nodes.

This is how zookeeper is configured on the hadoop master:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://ip-10-x.x.x:9000/hbase</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>ip-10-x.x.x</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/{username}/hbase/zookeeper</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I can't speak confidently about the internal implementation of seqware, but I know it uses the settings file to set the location of zookeepr and hbase master. In the default, pseudo-distributed working setup, these were the values for the variables I mentioned previously:

```
HBASE.ZOOKEEPER.QUORUM=localhost
HBASE.ZOOKEEPER.PROPERTY.CLIENTPORT=2181
HBASE.MASTER=localhost:60000
MAPRED.JOB.TRACKER=localhost:8021
FS.DEFAULT.NAME=hdfs://localhost:8020
FS.DEFAULTFS=hdfs://localhost:8020
```

This is what the zoo.cfg file looks like:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

maxClientCnxns=50
# The number of milliseconds of each tick
tickTime=2000
# The number of ticks that the initial
# synchronization phase can take
initLimit=10
# The number of ticks that can pass between
# sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=5
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
```

**Zookeeper stacktrace:**

`[seqware@master target]$ java -classpath seqware-distribution-0.13.6.8-qe-full.jar`

```
com.github.seqware.queryengine.system.ReferenceCreator hg_19 keyValue_ref.out 
[SeqWare Query Engine] 0 [main] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper - ZooKeeper exists failed after 3 retries
[SeqWare Query Engine] 1 [main] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher - hconnection Received unexpected KeeperException, re-throwing exception org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master at 
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99) at 
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51) at 
org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1021)   
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeep‌​er.java:154) at                org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.watchAndCheckExists(ZKUtil.java:226)at            org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker.start(ZooKeeperNodeTracke‌​r.java:82)  at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.setu‌​pZookeeperTrackers(HConnectionManager.java:580)
```

---

08/13/2013
Apparently the variables that need to be set for the remote hbase setup were not the ones I was editing, based on the the seqware constants.java file, they are the qe variables: https://github.com/SeqWare/seqware/blob/develop/seqware-queryengine/src/main/java/com/github/seqware/queryengine/Constants.java

I have edited them as such:

```
# SEQWARE QUERY ENGINE AND GENERAL HADOOP SETTINGS
#
HBASE.ZOOKEEPER.QUORUM=localhost
HBASE.ZOOKEEPER.PROPERTY.CLIENTPORT=2181
HBASE.MASTER=localhost:60000
MAPRED.JOB.TRACKER=localhost:8021
FS.DEFAULT.NAME=hdfs://localhost:8020
FS.DEFAULTFS=hdfs://localhost:8020
FS.HDFS.IMPL=org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem
#
# SEQWARE QUERY ENGINE SETTINGS
#
QE_NAMESPACE=SeqWareQE
QE_DEVELOPMENT_DEPENDENCY=file:/home/seqware/jars/seqware-distribution-0.13.6.5-qe-full.jar
QE_PERSIST=true
QE_HBASE_REMOTE_TESTING=true
QE_HBASE_PROPERTIES=HBOOT
QE_HBOOT_HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM=ip-10-x.x.x.ec2.internal
QE_HBOOT_HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_PROPERTY_CLIENTPORT=2181
QE_HBOOT_HBASE_MASTER=ip-10-x.x.x.ec2.internal:60010
QE_HBOOT_MAPRED_JOB_TRACKER=ip-10-x.x.x.ec2.internal:9001
QE_HBOOT_FS_DEFAULT_NAME=hdfs://ip-10-x.x.x.ec2.internal:9000
QE_HBOOT_FS_DEFAULTFS=hdfs://ip-10-x.x.x.ec2.internal:9000
QE_HBOOT_FS_HDFS_IMPL=org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem
```

I don't get the zookeeper exceptiona anymore, but the command to create the workspace just hangs for several minutes before I stop it.

I found this in my zookepper log, I'm not sure if it means, that zookeeper crashed or it lost connectivity to the clients it states. I don't know why it's accepting socket connections from the ports 36997,36998, 37000, and 37034, and I haven't even granted permission to them on the ec2 security group:

```
2013-08-13 16:44:55,560 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Established session 0x1407890cb630000 with negotiated timeout 180000 for client /10.x.x.x:36997
2013-08-13 16:44:57,633 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Accepted socket connection from /10.x.x.x:36998
2013-08-13 16:44:57,662 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Client attempting to establish new session at /10.x.x.x:36998
2013-08-13 16:44:57,666 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Established session 0x1407890cb630001 with negotiated timeout 180000 for client /10.x.x.x:36998
2013-08-13 16:44:57,917 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1407890cb630001 type:create cxid:0x8 zxid:0x219 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/online-snapshot/acquired Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/online-snapshot/acquired
2013-08-13 16:44:58,450 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1407890cb630000 type:create cxid:0xb zxid:0x21a txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/master Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/master
2013-08-13 16:45:00,927 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Accepted socket connection from /10.x.x.x:37000
2013-08-13 16:45:00,928 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Client attempting to establish new session at /10.x.x.x:37000
2013-08-13 16:45:00,930 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Established session 0x1407890cb630002 with negotiated timeout 180000 for client /10.x.x.x:37000
2013-08-13 16:45:02,165 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1407890cb630000 type:create cxid:0x24 zxid:0x221 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/online-snapshot/acquired Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/online-snapshot/acquired
2013-08-13 16:45:14,172 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Accepted socket connection from /10.x.x.x:37034
2013-08-13 16:45:14,173 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Client attempting to establish new session at /10.x.x.x:37034
2013-08-13 16:45:14,178 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Established session 0x1407890cb630003 with negotiated timeout 180000 for client /10.x.x.x:37034
2013-08-13 16:47:51,000 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Expiring session 0x1407800784a0003, timeout of 180000ms exceeded
2013-08-13 16:47:51,001 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Expiring session 0x1407800784a0001, timeout of 180000ms exceeded
2013-08-13 16:47:51,001 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Expiring session 0x1407800784a0000, timeout of 180000ms exceeded
2013-08-13 16:47:51,001 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Expiring session 0x1407800784a0002, timeout of 180000ms exceeded
2013-08-13 16:47:51,001 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x1407800784a0003
2013-08-13 16:47:51,001 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x1407800784a0001
2013-08-13 16:47:51,001 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x1407800784a0000
2013-08-13 16:47:51,002 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x1407800784a0002
```

I looked on the hbase web interface, its showing that the tables are actually being created, but the commands to create are never returning a reponse back, they just hang.
[image: Hbase master web interface tables]

[image: HBase Web Interface]

Comment: By which user is executing the ssh ip-10.x.x.x command? Type 'which' in the terminal and reply here.

Comment: It's being executed a user called seqware This is what I get when I type in which
'[seqware@master ~]$ which
Usage: /usr/bin/which [options] [--] programname [...]
Options: --version, -[vV] Print version and exit successfully.
         --help,          Print this help and exit successfully.

.
.
.'
it's not a sudoer, but I have the same problem for the instance running the hadoop master

Comment: So, where is your problem now? Only the ssh thing or Zookeeper connetion error? Because, I think ssh is not needed for connecting to a zookeeper server.

Comment: If you need, I can provide you a solution on the ssh problem but you have to tell me how this will help your connect to Zookeeper?

Comment: One more thing, are you sure Zookeeper is running? If you have a Zookeeper client, please try conneting to the Zookeeper and verify.

Comment: Zookeeper is running on the the master instance , and the instance that's running seqware needs to connect to zookeeper. If I try to create a namespace with the zookeeper quorum being the local host, theres no problem, but when I tell it, it's at ip-10.x.x.x, I get this error:

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide your zookeeper configuration details (/path/to/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg) ?

Comment: I guess this is hbase configuration file content you have provided. Make sure you provide Zookeeper's if you have any. It should be named `zoo.cfg` where your Zookeeper binaries are stored.

Comment: I found it, ill edit the question

Comment: So, HBASE.ZOOKEEPER.QUORUM=localhost worked for you and HBASE.ZOOKEEPER.QUORUM=ip-10-x.x.x didn't?

Comment: yes, and neither and neither did username@ip-10.x.x.x

Comment: I suggest you delete your Zookeeper stacktraces in the comments. I have added them in the question itself. Thanks!

Comment: Is hbase running properly?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35312/discussion-between-jtherocker-and-amre)

Comment: Hbase is running properly, I can post a screenshot of the web page in the question. I can't access the stackoverflow chat, at my work network, for some reason, they feel it needs to be blocked, is it possible to continue the dissuasion in about 2 hours or anytime laterthat you are free. I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing,

```
<property>
   <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
   <value>ip-10-x.x.x</value>
</property>
```

to this,

```
<property>
   <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
   <value>localhost</value>
</property>
```

**Then restart hbase and Zookeeper**

And, also suggest this as your seqware configuration

```
# SEQWARE QUERY ENGINE AND GENERAL HADOOP SETTINGS
#
HBASE.ZOOKEEPER.QUORUM=localhost
HBASE.ZOOKEEPER.PROPERTY.CLIENTPORT=2181
HBASE.MASTER=localhost:60000
MAPRED.JOB.TRACKER=localhost:8021
FS.DEFAULT.NAME=hdfs://localhost:8020
FS.DEFAULTFS=hdfs://localhost:8020
FS.HDFS.IMPL=org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem
#
# SEQWARE QUERY ENGINE SETTINGS
#
QE_NAMESPACE=SeqWareQE
QE_DEVELOPMENT_DEPENDENCY=file:/home/seqware/jars/seqware-distribution-0.13.6.5-qe-full.jar
QE_PERSIST=true
QE_HBASE_REMOTE_TESTING=true
QE_HBASE_PROPERTIES=HBOOT
QE_HBOOT_HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM=ip-10-x.x.x.ec2.internal
QE_HBOOT_HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_PROPERTY_CLIENTPORT=2181
QE_HBOOT_HBASE_MASTER=ip-10-x.x.x.ec2.internal:60010
QE_HBOOT_MAPRED_JOB_TRACKER=ip-10-x.x.x.ec2.internal:9001
QE_HBOOT_FS_DEFAULT_NAME=hdfs://ip-10-x.x.x.ec2.internal:9000
QE_HBOOT_FS_DEFAULTFS=hdfs://ip-10-x.x.x.ec2.internal:9000
QE_HBOOT_FS_HDFS_IMPL=org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem
```

Also, try the guides [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/seqware/index.php?title=Setup_SeqWare_Query_Engine_with_HBase)  and [here](http://seqware.github.io/docs/github_readme/2-queryengine/).

You also mentioned about a probably Zookeeper ports has not been opened. For testing pupose, I suggest you disable firewall. Because I have earlier seen several issues that's because of firewall blocking important ports.

Comment: I getting it apparently for the old seqware setup as well now

Comment: scratch that last one, apparently I had to reboot it

Comment: I think, resolving the ssh problem would resolve it. The inly other time I had this error with zookeeper, was if the process wasn't running when I started up the instance

Comment: So how are you starting your zookeeper? I thought it's already started.

Comment: Do you have seqware's home directory? i.e. somthing like /home/seqware/?

Comment: If i'm doing it in pseudo-distributed mode, so out of the box, zookeeper is started when the seqware instance is. If zookeeper is shutdown, and I try to use seqware I get that error. At the moment I have zookeeper running on the master node of my cluster, and I'm trying to connect seqware to it.

Comment: I'm not sure if zookeeper is running corectly, I'll ost the log file output in the question, Also I found that the varaibles that seqware uses for a a remote hbase setup are different, I'll post them in the question as well

Comment: I looked at the hbase master status using the webinterface, it shows that the seqware table hve been created, such as the refernce set, and tag set table, I'll post an image in the question, but the command called frm the seqware instance never returns

Comment: with which IP address are you accessing your hbase webinterface?

Comment: I point my web browser to the public dns of the hbase master instance
so, the ip-10.x.x.x of the master node
The page says "Master: ip-10-x.x.x.ec2.internal:60000" at the top

Comment: I have edited my answer, try changing, QE_HBOOT_HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM to localhost

Comment: I changed it, it crashes with a zookeeperconnectionloss exception

Comment: I have modified the configurations and added some text at the last. See if this helps.